# Determining All Groups of Order 308

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I just turned in an exam today and I wanted to answer this question, but I couldn't so I had to choose another (you could omit one question).

> Up to isomorphism, we had to determine all groups of order 308.

I know that I have to use the Sylow theorems. We can have just one Sylow subgroup of order 11, we can have 1 Sylow subgroup of order 7 or 22 Sylow 7-subgroups, and 1,11,7,or 77 sylow 2-subgroups. I know I need to consider the eight cases and break it down from there, but I don't know how...

Comment: Have you seen other examples worked out in detail?

Comment: Hint:  If there's just one subgroup of order 11 (call it $H$), that subgroup must be normal.  So (writing $G$ for the group of order 308), we have a quotient group $G/H$ of order 28.  It would be helpful to know what that group is.  So start by classifying groups of order 28.

Comment: No, I've never seen examples like this worked out in detail. I have the Gallian textbook, and it has examples, but I am having trouble following similar steps for 308.

Answer (score 3):

Hints for you to understand and/or prove:

There exists only one single Sylow subgroup of order $\;11\;$ and one unique one of order $\;7\;$. Denote them by $\;P_{11}\,,\,P_7\;$ , resp. Then, the group $\;Q:=P_{11}P_7\cong P_{11}\times P_7\;$ is cyclic and normal, from where we get that any group $\;G\;$ of order $\;308\;$ is a semidirect produc $\;T\rtimes Q\;$ , with $\;|T|=2^2=4\;$ .

Since $\;|\text{Aut}\,( Q)|=10\cdot 6=60\;$,  there exist non-trivial homomorphisms $\;T\to\text{Aut} (Q)\;$ : at least two (or even three) if $\;T\cong V\cong C_2\times C_2\;$ , and at least two if $\;T\cong C_4\;$, and together with the two non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $\;308\;$ , we already have at least $\;6/7\;$ non-isomorphic groups of order $\;308\;$ . Continue from here.

Comment: Why is the number of $7$-Sylow subgroups 1 and not 22?

Comment: I thought that you could have either 1 Sylow 7-subgroup or 22 Sylow 7-subgroups.

Comment: Also, DonAntonio, thank you so much! I understand the beginning about semidirect products, but is there another way of determining without using non-trivial homomorphisms? We didn't learn about them in class, and I'm happy to learn about them now to solve the problem, but I'm really curious about how to solve it with the knowledge I had at the time of the take-home exam.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches, both through the Sylow $11$-subgroup.

1. Let $|G|=308$. Since $308=2^2\cdot 7\cdot 11$, we see that the number of Sylow $11$-subgroups is $1$ (it's one of $1$, $2$, $4$, $7$, $14$ and $28$, and only $1$ is $1$ modulo $11$). Let $P$ denote the unique, normal Sylow $11$-subgroup of $G$. The quotient group $G/P$ has order $28$, and has a unique Sylow $7$-subgroup, $R/P$. If $Q$ is any Sylow $7$-subgroup of $G$, then $|QP/P|=7$, so $QP=R$. Thus every Sylow $7$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in $R$. But $|R|=77=7\cdot 11$, so has a unique Sylow $7$-subgroup, as needed.
2. This starts as before, to obtain a unique Sylow $11$-subgroup $P$. Then $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of the automorphism group of $P$, which has order $10$. Since $7\nmid 10$, $7\mid |C_G(P)|$, so there is a Sylow $7$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$ centralizing $P$. Thus $11\mid |C_G(Q)|\mid |N_G(Q)|$, so in particular $|G:N_G(Q)|\neq 22$.

Since there is a unique Sylow $7$- and $11$-subgroup, they centralize one another and $G$ is a semidirect product $C_{77}\rtimes C_4$ or $C_{77}\rtimes (C_2\times C_2)$.

To complete the proof, we need to count maps from the Sylow $2$-subgroup $R$ into $\mathrm{Aut}(C_7\times C_{11})\cong C_6\times C_{10}$. If $R\cong C_4$ then the kernel of the map is at least $C_2$, so there are four possible images, according as the image is $1$, the $C_2$ in the first fact, the second fact, or both diagonally.

For $C_2\times C_2$ there are five maps: the unique faithful map, the unique trivial map, and then the three previous maps with kernel of order $2$.

This yields nine groups in total.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! And yet how do we find the nontrivial homomorphisms from the chosen Sylow-$2$ group $H(2)$ to $\text{Aut}(R)$, especially the case for $H(2)=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$? How to determine the number of subgroups of order $4$ in $\text{Aut}(R)$?

Comment: @barbatos233 With a normal Sylow $11$- and $7$-subgroup, they must centralize each other.  The automorphism group of a group of prime order $p$ is $C_{p-1}$, so the automorphism group of $C_{11}\times C_7$ is $C_{10}\times C_6$. It has no elements of order $4$. If the Sylow $2$-subgroup is $C_4$ there are four options, depending on whether the $4$ inverts the $7$, the $11$, both or neither. For $C_2\times C_2$, we count based on the $2$-part of $|Z(G)|$. If this is $4$ or $1$ you get one group, and if it is $2$ you get three, as with the $C_4$ case.